# How to make svg symbols dropshadow

Tags: d3.js, svg, symbols

I tried to append filter to a path using svg.symbols but it is not appeared.

This is my code

```js
    let namngu = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", "5000")
        .attr("height", "5000");
        let namnguvcl = namngu.append("defs")
        let filter = namnguvcl.append("filters")
        .attr("id", "drop-shadow-line");

      filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
      .attr("in","SourceAlpha")
      .attr("stdDeviation",4)

      let namnhuconbo = filter.append("feMerge")
      namnhuconbo.append("feMergeNode")
      namnhuconbo.append("feMergeNode")
      .attr("in","SourceGraphic")

     let namngunhucho = namnguvcl.append("symbol") 
      .attr("id","may")
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 17275 8599")
      
       namngunhucho.append("svg:path")
       .attr("d", "M 5097.99967 2512.5 q 67 -30 134 0")
       .attr("style", "fill: transparent; stroke: blue")
       
    namngu.append("use")
    .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow-line)")
    .attr("xlink:href","#may")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pn9ta08w/

This is what I am trying to replicate https://jsfiddle.net/fonwrspj/3/

How can I fix this, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Errors in the resulting SVG code:

1. In your code you have `<filters>` instead of `<filter>`
2. The symbol has a viewBox but the use element has no width and height
3. The svg element is huge and has no viewBox attribute
4. The viewBox attribute of the symbol is enormous compares with the bounding box of the shape.

After correcting all this the filter gets applied.

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 150 75">
  <defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow-line" y="-1" height="20">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <symbol id="may" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="5090 2490 150 50">    
      <path d="M 5097.99967 2512.5 q 67 -30 134 0" style="fill:transparent; stroke: blue"></path>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#may"  width="150" height="150" style="filter: url('#drop-shadow-line')" />
</svg>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0m95rk2w/
I followed your method but I cant display it on d3.js, I don`t know why

Comment: You have a typo:  use `viewBox` instead of `viewbox`